# How do I uninstall LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, lamp

am a bit new on ubuntu
I see everywhere how to install, and install LAMP.

But, I can't find any tutorial showing how to uninstall, 
Am using [Bitnami Installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/horde/installer) And it brings already LAMP, but MySQL inside BITNAMI is getting mad couse I have the other MySQL installed on the system.

or, at least would like to uninstall MySQL (couse maybe its not a good idea uninstall php from the system)

Any tips? thanks!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu package management. It would be a better fit for askubuntu.com

Answer (score 8):

Removing XAMPP from Ubuntu is simple. Follow the following steps:

1. XAMPP gets itself installed in `opt/lampp` directory by default
2. Stop the XAMPP server by typing `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop` in the Terminal (you can open the terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+t`)
3. Now type `sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp`
4. Check your opt directory; The folder “lampp” would have been removed
5. You have successfully removed XAMPP from your Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Removing XAMPP from Ubuntu is simple. Follow the following steps:

1. XAMPP gets itself installed in “`opt/lampp`” directory by default.
2. Stop the XAMPP server by typing `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop` in the Terminal (you can open the terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+t).
3. Now type `sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp`
4. Check your opt directory. The folder “lampp” would have been removed.
5. You have successfully removed XAMPP from your Ubuntu.